# .htaccess URL rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, pattern-matching

I've run into a problem when trying to rewrite a url that has a # in it. The rewrite itself is simple:

```
RewriteRule ^accessories/access/Roll-Up-PR30/accessories.php#a485$ /alog/roll-up-product.php
```

But it just falls over and will not let me have the hash in there.

Any feedback is welcome as I am running out of ideas :S

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately most browsers (that I know of) don't send the fragment part of the URL to the server so it's not available in `.htaccess`; it's just a client-side anchor lookup.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that hashes are a special case. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

The relevant section is "Extended Redirection"

```
RewriteRule ^xredirect:(.+) /path/to/nph-xredirect.cgi/$1 \
            [T=application/x-httpd-cgi,L]
```